Merge audio streams with ffmpeg in nodejs into one stream seamlessly?
I've been working on a music bot for DnD which we are using as our main source of music in Discord.
Discord is not important as it accepts pretty much any stream.
What i want to achieve:I want to have one stream playing music, and i want to have one other stream, that can dynamically load mp3 files, that could be played briefly in the middly of the music files. So.. basically a soundboard. I've seen discord do this with their soundpad feature, where it can seamlessly incorporate audio into others mic audio.
How can one achieve that?
I've tried using something similar to this
  this.currentFfmpegCommand
        .complexFilter([
          `[0:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,aresample=async=1[a0]`,
          `[1:a]apad[a1]`,
          `[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2`,
        ])
        .input(soundPath)
        .run();

But honestly.. i have no idea what i am doingm as this does not output whatever i wanted it to..
